# ¿Como cambiar tamaño de linearlayout con porcentajes en android studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, diseño

Necesito cambiar el tamaño de un linearlayout pero necesito que ocupe el 30% de la pantalla y usando el  android:layout_height="30%" no funciona, como podria hacerlo, gracias de antemano.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="30%"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imagenC"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Nombre Categoria"/>
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>


</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Todavía no tengo mucho conocimiento de Android. Pero, me parece que CardView debe "crecer" con sus contenidos. Te sugiero probar usando un **NestedScrollView** y asignarle la altura que deseas. Como el permite deslizar dentro del interior visible es posible que acepte el 30% sin problemas. No lo he probado pero, me parece que tiene sentido.

Comment: Acabo de probar y no pude asignar el atributo. Mi entorno indica error. IGNORA mi comentario anterior. Es erróneo.

Answer (score 0):

Se que es de hace 5 años pero lo pongo porque seguro alguien entra y le sirve.

Yo lo que hago es, primero definir las columnas que tiene tu linearlayout, esto lo haces con el atributo weightSum, en tu caso seria 2 (que representan tu imageview y tu otro linearlayout)

Dentro de estas 2 etiquetas para definir que porcentaje van a ocupar en la pantalla, lo haces con el atributo layout_weight, si quieres que sean 50% para ambos pondrías 1 y 1, si quieres poner 30% y 70% seria aproximadamente 0.7 y 1.3.

Como tienes 2 columnas, la suma de los valores tendría que llegar a 2.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="30%"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="2"

        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imagenC"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="1.3"
            android:background="@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_height="0.7">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Nombre Categoria"/>
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>


</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```